# How does magento calculate max uses per coupon for a promo rule

Tags: magento-enterprise, coupon-codes

I have observed that customers can no longer apply a specific promocode to their orders although the uses registered per coupon are lower than the value set in the rule.  The only way I have to solve the issue is to increase the value for uses per coupon (uses per customer is set to 1 always).

At reviewing the DB, I see that coupon is used in the sales_flat_quote as well in sales_flat_orders. Don't know if this is the expected behaviour (summing up quotes + orders for uses calculations) or if there's a bug I should report / correct.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see how Magento checks if a coupon can be applied you need to look into `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` in the `_canProcessRule($rule, $address)` method.

```
    if ($rule->getCouponType() != Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
        $couponCode = $address->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
        if (strlen($couponCode)) {
            $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
            $coupon->load($couponCode, 'code');
            if ($coupon->getId()) {
                // check entire usage limit
                if ($coupon->getUsageLimit() && $coupon->getTimesUsed() >= $coupon->getUsageLimit()) {
                    $rule->setIsValidForAddress($address, false);
                    return false;
                }
                // check per customer usage limit
                $customerId = $address->getQuote()->getCustomerId();
                if ($customerId && $coupon->getUsagePerCustomer()) {
                    $couponUsage = new Varien_Object();
                    Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_usage')->loadByCustomerCoupon(
                        $couponUsage, $customerId, $coupon->getId());
                    if ($couponUsage->getCouponId() &&
                        $couponUsage->getTimesUsed() >= $coupon->getUsagePerCustomer()
                    ) {
                        $rule->setIsValidForAddress($address, false);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Magento will check the usage limit and the times used of the coupon from the `salesrule_coupon` table. It will also check the usage per customer from the `salesrule_coupon_usage` table.

The `times_used` column of both tables is updated by `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer` observer on the `sales_order_place_after` event. So the coupons that are used in quotes are not considered.

If you've set the uses per customer value to 1, then a customer will only be able to use that coupon for one order (even if the order gets cancelled).